# Get Sheet ID from Sheet created by another function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a function that creates a form and a destination sheet for responses. I want to then reference that sheet from another function that sends out an email on form submit.

Since the create form and sheet function will be run more than once the sheet ID I need to reference will change. Trying to find ways to get it into my email function as a parameter.

```
function createform () {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(fname);
var ssID = ss.getId();
form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());

ScriptApp.newTrigger('makeReport').forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function makeReport(thispara) {

//Open Response SS
var responseSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thispara).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var respRange = responseSS.getDataRange();
var respName = respRange.getValues();  

}
```

Comment: Save in `PropertiesService`?

Comment: @TheMaster that's it! Thank you!

Comment: The variables `fname` and  `form` had not being declared. Please add a [mcve].